# Union 'expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression'

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I'm trying to do a union select, 4 of the columns in my first query is a number, I don't need this 4 numbers in my second query so I just want to display a '0' or null for those columns in the second query.

My query is something like this

```
Select Column A, Column B, Number A, Number B, Number C, Number D
   From Table A
UNION
Select Column A, Column B
   From Table B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill the values.

```
Select Column A, Column B, Number A, Number B, Number C, Number D
   From Table A
UNION
Select Column A, Column B, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
   From Table B
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can just do

```
Select Column A, Column B, Number A, Number B, Number C, Number D
From Table A
UNION
Select Column A, Column B, 0, 0, 0, 0
From Table B
```